# Android Studio - IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problems. See IDEA-78860 for details

Tags: android, android-studio, updates, ubuntu-15.10

`Android Studio 1.5`
`Build #AI-141.2422023, built on November 12, 2015`

I just updated my `Android Studio` on `Ubuntu 15.10` when it gave me the prompt that a new version is available. After the patch download was finished, I chose the option to use my previous Android Studio settings when it asked for the prompt. But after that it is giving me the `cannot resolve symbol ...` error everywhere in the project and also showing me the pop-up warning

> **System Health**
>   IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problems. See IDEA-78860 for details.

I have tried `cleaning` and `rebuilding` the project. But nothing is working. What do I do? Please Help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

When IDEA is used on a system with IBus is installed and running keyboard input sometimes became blocked by IBus daemon. Event Dispatching Thread is active. All other events are delivered in order - i.e. it is possible to select text or call menu actions by a mouse.

Solution:
Either upgrade IBus to version 1.5.11 or add "export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1" to your ~/.profile, then restart a session.

Alternatively, you can turn off IBus at System Settings | Language Support | Keyboard input method.

IDEA 15 will show a warning if an incompatible version of IBus is in use.

checkout this link for detals https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860

Comment: Going through the link you provided, I assume that this problem is not even remotely attached to `Android Studio` giving errors everywhere after the update, if  I am not wrong. The problem with IBus is completely different. That said, can you tell me how to upgrade my IBus? I found this link (http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/wily/main/base/ibus), should I use it?