# System Health : IBus prior Issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Currently I'm facing issue in my android studio. whenever I start/restart my android studio. I don't know how to handle this..

`IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problems. See IDEA-78860 for details.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of studio?

Comment: I also facing this problem,my version is 1.5 ,the latest version.@JaredBurrows

Comment: Android studio 1.5 latest updated, but I faced this issue in 1.4 too. Still can't able to solve this...

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823742/android-studio-ibus-prior-to-1-5-11-may-cause-input-problems-see-idea-78860-f

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving IBus Issue - IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651898/resolving-ibus-issue-ibus-prior-to-1-5-11-may-cause-input-problems)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Ubuntu.
Go to System Settings>Language Support.

Change the value of Keyboard input method to none instead of default value 'ibus'.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I will get back to you as soon as possible